# Line up ts or zoo timeseries of different frequencies at "midperiod" on X axis

Tags: r, time-series

I need to plot a number of time series of different frequencies in R, and I need them to have the points centered on a period instead of starting at the beginning of each period. Here is an illustration of what I'm running into:

```
test1 <- ts(rnorm(24), start=2004, freq=12)
test2 <- ts(rnorm(2), start=2004, freq=1)
plot(test1, type='l')
lines(test2, col='red')
```

I'd like the red line to essentially be shifted forward 6 months, to the middle oaf each year. I've spent a little time with the R documentation for "ts" and haven't figured out how to do this -- any suggestions?

Comment: Both answers were useful; DWin thanks for noting the accessor methods! I think I've come up with a reasonable, workable solution from this, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @haggai_e that shifting the 'start' parameter makes sense, but if you already have a ts-object then the code to use those values would be:

```
lines(ts(test2, start=2004.5, freq=frequency(test2)) )
```

ts-objects are really just numeric vectors with attributes. You recover those attributes with `start`, `end` and `frequency`. The `end` is actually calculated on the fly from(`length/frequency -1` ) of the vector added to `start`.

Answer (score 2):

How about changing the time-series start?

```
test2 <- ts(rnorm(2), start=2004.5, freq=1)
```